# Removing exceeding overlay symbols off the board border in Altium

Tags: altium

[image: Image of the problem in question]

As you can see in the image, I have a symbol in the overlay layer that exceeds the board border. I want to keep the symbol for aesthetical reasons but I would like to cut out any part that exceeds the board as I don't know if the manufacturer will like it and I would like to see how the board will really come out. My though was to intersect the symbol with a rectangle with the shape of the board but I haven't been able to find any way to do it. Any thoughts?

Comment: They'll remove it automatically. Ask for check/review files to be sure.

Comment: You may be able to add a rule to cut it off outside of the board outline. That being said, the manufacturer will remove it during fabrication.